# I am not able to scan my bar code (escpos printer)

Tags: python, barcode-scanner, escpos

Here is my sample program i want to scan this bar code  but i am not able to do that.Can any one please explain why my bar code  is not scanning by the hardware scanner device.But using the smart phone scanner i am able to read the bar code value. Thank you in advanced.

Given below is sample code:

```
from escpos import printer
from escpos import printer
Epson = printer.Usb(0x154f,0x154f,0,0x81,0x02)
Epson.barcode('1324354657687', 'CODE128', function_type="B")
Epson.cut()
```

Comment: Is this question about _printing_ a barcode, or _scanning_ a barcode?

Comment: So why have you posted code for printing barcodes if the printing is actually working? It sounds like you have a problem with your scanner, not a problem with your Python code.